# django2: How to use different templates?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Say I created a django project called `django_site`.

I created two sub-projects: `site1` and `polls`.

You see that I have two `index.html` in two sub-projects directories.

However, now, if I open on web browser `localhost:8000/site1` or `localhost:8000/polls`, they all point to the `index.html` of `polls`.

How can I configure so when I open `localhost:8000/site1` it will use the `index.html` of `site1`?

My `settings.py` in `django_site` directory:

```
..
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

..
```

My directory structure:

```
E:.
|   db.sqlite3
|   manage.py
|   tree.txt
|   tree1.txt
|   
+---site1
|   |   admin.py
|   |   apps.py
|   |   models.py
|   |   tests.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   views.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---migrations
|   |       __init__.py
|   |       
|   +---templates
|   |   \---site1
|   |       \---templates
|   |               index.html
|   |               
|   \---__pycache__
|           models.cpython-36.pyc
|           urls.cpython-36.pyc
|           views.cpython-36.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
|           
+---django_site
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   \---__pycache__
|           settings.cpython-36.pyc
|           urls.cpython-36.pyc
|           wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
|           
\---polls
    |   admin.py
    |   apps.py
    |   models.py
    |   tests.py
    |   urls.py
    |   views.py
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    +---migrations
    |   |   0001_initial.py
    |   |   0002_auto_20180214_0906.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   \---__pycache__
    |           0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
    |           0002_auto_20180214_0906.cpython-36.pyc
    |           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    |           
    +---static
    |       jquery-3.3.1.min.js
    |       
    +---templates
    |   \---polls
    |       \---templates
    |               index.html
    |               
    \---__pycache__
            admin.cpython-36.pyc
            apps.cpython-36.pyc
            models.cpython-36.pyc
            urls.cpython-36.pyc
            views.cpython-36.pyc
            __init__.cpython-36.pyc
```

My `urls.py` in `django_site`

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('site1/', include('site1.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My `urls.py` in `site1` or `polls` (they are the same):

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: could you post your urls.py files?

Comment: I added them. Thanks

Comment: Please show your `index` views.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure urls like this :

In your `django_site directory` you have an url file. You have to get urls from all your django apps :

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

from polls import views
from site1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('site1/', include('site1.urls')),
    ]
```

Then, inside each django module, you should have :

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.your_function, name="index"),
    ]
```

and the same thing for `site1` :

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

from site1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.your_function, name="index"),
    ]
```

`views.your_function` have to return your index template : `index.html`

Your function could be :

```
def MyFunction(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

In this way, you have to get : `path('', views.MyFunction, name="index"),`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by:

In `views.py` in `site1` or `polls`:

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

And inside `django_site` I created a folder `templates`, then in this folder there are two folders `site1` and `polls`. In each subfolder I put `index.html` respectively.

Comment: To my mind, It's not the good way. Each templates should be set in the good subdirectory.